# Eiffel: a way to check type conformance with a given CLASS_NAME

Tags: standards-compliance, eiffel

I'm trying to do something as

```
work (a_father: FATHER)
    do
        if a_father.conforms_to ({DEVELOPER}) then
           a_father.code
        else
           a_father.change_job ({DEVELOPER})
        end
    end
```

[image]
[image]

the compilation works, but in my implementation @runtime it doesn't pass. What did I mistype?

Comment: I don't think that you can change the type of argument you receive. Maybe you could have a `job` attributes in `FATHER` to know if it is a `developer`.

Comment: @LouisM thx, but that would be a workaround and adding some trick to get the type of an object, not a type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd better use a built-in mechanism to check object type conformance:

```
if attached {DEVELOPER} a_father as dev then
     dev.code
else
     a_father.rest
end
```

And use the same approach in the precondition:

```
attached {RELATED_DB_ENTITY} a_relationship_entity
```

The object test does what you would like to: it checks that the type of the object attached to argument `a_relationship_entity` conforms to type `RELATED_DB_ENTITY`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your example is that you are trying to see whether the type `FATHER` (type of the object `a_father`) conforms to the type `TYPE [DEVELOPER]` (the type of the object `{DEVELOPER}`).

What you should do is:

```
if a_father.generating_type.is_conforming_to ({DEVELOPER}) then
```

hence comparing `TYPE [FATHER]` with `TYPE [DEVELOPER]`.

Note that I would assume that it would work by replacing `is_conforming_to` by `conforms_to`, but class `TYPE` introduced this routine `is_conforming_to` with a more specific argument type.

Comment: Thx, why is that so? Seems that there are 2 definitions of conformity check `conforms_to (other: ANY)` `is_conforming_to (other: like Current)` your solution should work but passing through a type comparison. Seems that I'm trying to compare 2 different objects (in nature) an object descendent from FATHER & DEVELOPER, and another of TYPE[DEVELOPER] which are not conform one to the other. Does that make sense for you? maybe you could enhance your answer if thats so...

Comment: I'm not sure how you want me to enhance my answer. I already mentioned that you were trying to compare `FATHER` with `TYPE [DEVELOPER]` instead of `TYPE [FATHER]` with `TYPE [DEVELOPER]`.